# Unexpected results getting contents of spotify playlist

Tags: c#, spotify

I need to keep a database up-to-date with a playlist's contents.

I am using the C# Wrapper for the libspotify api - http://libspotify-sharp.hallerud.se/

My work flow is as follows at present

Login, wait for playlist container to load, when loaded listen for playlist loaded events, when the playlist I am interested in is loaded wait for all the tracks on the playlist to have loaded, then write the contents to the db.

I am completely clearing the cache directory everytime the program starts.

I am finding this works fine and as expected most of the time, then when deleting some of the tracks within the normal spotify client, that the tracks still seem to get returned by the api even though they are no longer there (I am clearing the cache directory so they must be?).

Does anyone know what could cause this?

UPDATE

What I am finding is that the API seems to return different information to what is viewable in the client. I have run the console app from different computers and the tracks which have been removed are still being returned. The normal spotify client does not show these, also tested on multiple computers. In my app I login, wait for the playlists to have loaded fully and then exit, this app is on a scheduled task.

UPDATE 2

I am currently waiting until

```
(playlist.IsLoaded == true && 
playlist.CurrentTracks.All(x => x.IsLoaded && x.Artists.Count() > 0))
```

using

```
session.OnMetaDataUpdated += HandleOnMetaUpdated;
```

and

```
playlist.OnMetadataUpdated += PlaylistMetaUpdated;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the playlist backend is running slowly, it can take a little while for changes made in the client to make it to the Spotify backend. Only once they're in the backend will the changes make it down to other clients.

Comment: Have updated my question a bit. When you say the backend are you referring to the normal windows client? Some of the tracks I removed on Friday and they are still being returned 3 days later. Am wondering how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: No, by "backend" I mean the Spotify servers. You can double-check by installing the Spotify client on a new machine and see what it displays for your playlists. Also, beware that playlist changes are sent to libSpotify as deltas, so you may be looking at the list before the "Delete these tracks" delta is received. There are APIs on sp_playlistcontainer to check what's going on.

Comment: The Spotify Client is showing the playlist with tracks removed on multiple computers while the console app is showing them still existing on multiple computers. What Api calls do I need to be using? Have updated the question again with exactly what I am currently using to check.

Comment: I am currently waiting until 
    (playlist.IsLoaded == true && 
    playlist.CurrentTracks.All(x => x.IsLoaded && x.Artists.Count() > 0))
using 
    session.OnMetaDataUpdated += HandleOnMetaUpdated;
and
    playlist.OnMetadataUpdated += PlaylistMetaUpdated;

Comment: Figured it out.. wasn't anything wrong with the application, was that the client was hiding the tracks as they weren't playable in my region. Thanks for your help!